# Discard floating numbers from string list

Tags: python, regex

am trying to ignore a float value from a string and filing to do so.

```
string = ['20', '30', '40', '.50', '0.60', 'OA', '2A']
```

code :

```
match = []
for i in string:
     if re.match('(?<![\.\d])[0-9]+(?![\.\d])', i):
              match.append(i)
print(match)
```

output : `['20', '30', '40']`

This code is ignoring two elements as they are not numerical `'OA', '2A'`

expected output:

```
['20', '30', '40', 'OA', '2A']
```

Comment: You are not matching `[0-9A-Z]+` only digits 0-9

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
import re

lst = ['20', '30', '40', '.50', '0.60', 'OA', '2A']

pattern = re.compile(r'-?\d*\.\d+$')

output = [item for item in lst if not pattern.match(item)]
print(output)
```

This yields

```
['20', '30', '40', 'OA', '2A']
```

---

`re.match()` implicitely adds an anchor in the beginning, so the actual pattern is

```
^-?\d*\.\d+$
```

As @Wiktor points out, `Python 3.x` has [**`re.fullmatch()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), so you could use

```
pattern = re.compile(r'-?\d*\.\d+')
output = [item for item in lst if not pattern.fullmatch(item)]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lz6pFX/2).

Comment: Since most people already use Python3, I'd suggest to use `re.fullmatch` when full string match is required.